# Shabbos and Playfoam

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, games-toys

Shemirat Shabbat KeHilchata 16:13 brings down that plaster, clay, wax, and the like may not be molded on shabbos. (footnote 36 quotes SA and says it's due to mimareach)

As far as I'm aware, a collection of objects like a [magnetic sculpture](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01C5P1AFQ) may be played with on shabbos, since it is comprised of distinct individual pieces - no actual violation of mimareach is taking place.

What about something like [playfoam](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00486Y5XA), which functions much like clay but is ultimately comprised of small, distinct foam balls? Is this considered to be like a collection of magnets? Or is it closer to clay, since it is held together by a tacky polymer and not through magnetism?

Comment: Sorry can't source it right now but check igros moshe about mashing bananas on shabbos. It may be relevant.

Comment: @user6591 looked up a reference - that's dealing with tochein and food, not memareach for non-food. Interesting, but I'm not sure it's relevant.

Comment: True. I just thought his idea about considering the banana mush as separate particles held together and not one homogeneous lump might've been somewhat relevant to the issue you raised here.